# use beautifulsoup to find all tags with attributes of some form

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

i need to find all tags which have any mouse event registered inline
for example, it should find tags like :

```
<div onmousedown="somefunc()"> Some text here </div>
```

i could check using a function as given in bs4 docs :

```
def reg_event(tag):
    return tag.has_key('onmousedown')
tags_with_mouse_event = soup.find_all(reg_event)
```

but check for multiple ones need many .has_key combined with or.. is there some simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

You could pick out all tags with an `on..` attribute like:

```
soup.find_all(lambda tag: any(attr.startswith('on') for attr in tag.attrs.keys()))
```

Otherwise, make a `set` of what events you're after and do something such as:

```
events = {'onmousedown', 'onmouseup', 'onclick'} # etc...
soup.find_all(lambda tag: any(attr in events for attr in tag.attrs.keys()))
```